# How to send json object present in EC2 to angular app?

Tags: json, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I have an angular app that takes a file as input, which is stored in S3.Then i used SQS to connect to EC2, where some big computations happen.After the computations happen i get a json object which i want to use in angular app. How to do that?

File as input --> S3 --> use SQS to connect to EC2 --> processing in EC2 which returns json object

Now how do i get that json in angular?

One thing i thought was to store processed final json in a different S3 and access that file in angular.But i need some notification when that json file is stored in different S3.
Second thing i thought was to use something like API Gateway.But I dont know how to go about doing that.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable approach. Good luck

Comment: @Felix Which of the two - S3 one or API Gateway?

Comment: you will have to start writing some code. for example, how do you envision getting to S3 from Angular. The way it's written, your question is not suitable for Stack Overflow. But since you are new, it's an opportunity for you to read the site [help] and [ask], and this question [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: @Felix I already have the code from taking file as input in angular to creating json in EC2. I want to know what after getting that json?More specifically, I want to get some notification in angular when that json is returned.